# When I push the button, it writes letter "A" in textaria. I want that whenever I push letter "A", it writes "A"

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, textarea

When I push the button, it writes letter "A" in textaria. I want that whenever I push letter "A", it writes "A".

```
<textarea id="text"> </textarea>
<input type="submit" name="as"  value="a" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QXePf/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input").click(function(){
  $('#text').text($('#text').text() + 'a');
});
```

So for textarea's you get their value by using `.text()`

To change it's value you pass the value into `.text(value)`

So everytime you click, we get the current value `$('#text').text()`
we add an 'a' to it `+ 'a'`

Then we change the value of the text area by passing it into `.text()` like this `.text($('#text').text() + 'a')`

http://jsfiddle.net/QXePf/1/

Answer (score 0):

By using directly the [value] attribute of the clicked element :

```
$("input").click(function(){
    $("#text").val($("#text").val() + $(this).attr("value"));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

See the complete code:

```
$("input").click(function(){
  $('#text').val($('#text').val() + 'A'); // add "A" when button is clicked
});

$(document).keyup(function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode == 65)
    $('#text').val($('#text').val() + 'A'); // add "A" when "A" in keyboard is pressed
});
```

[Demo!](http://jsfiddle.net/QXePf/2/)